# Max bandwidth at any given time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have input of startTime, endTime and bandwidth consumed.
like

```
1234  5678   12
2345  6789   10
7900  8790   20
6790  8123   8
```

We have to calculate max bandwithd consumed. Like for above it will be 28 from input set `{7900 8790}{6790 8123}` since these sets has intersection.

What will be the best approach to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make pairs

```
{t; v} 
where 
t=time
v = +bandwidth for start of interval or 
    -bandwidth for end of interval
```

Sort list of these pair by time (in case of tie +first).

```
1234; 12
5678; -12
2345; 10
6789;  -10
7900; 20
8790;- 20
6790; 8
8123; -8
```

Walk through this list, adding v to the current bandwidth value. Maximal reached value is what you need

```
1234; 12     : 12
2345; 10     : 22
5678; -12    : 10
6789;  -10   : 0
6790; 8      : 8
7900; 20     : 28
8123; -8     : 20
8790;- 20    : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method should be like the following pseudo code, which is `O(n lg n)` . Also I think your example answer should be 28 as [6790, 8123] and [7900, 8790] has intersection too.

```
Sort_interval()
int ans = 0, sum = 0;
For each interval i
    if interval i intersect with interval i-1
        sum += bandwidth(i)
    else
        ans = max(ans, sum)
        sum = bandwidth(i)
Output ans
```

Comment: How do you sort the intervals?, And if every interval intersect with previous interval, then you will output 0 and the else case will not happened

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Sort the interval by start time, and it is pseudo code which outline the idea only, I did not handle the first interval does not has previous interval as well, if you must say that